# how to start multi-thead using a loop rightly in TCL?

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I want to get 200 files using multithread, so I modify a TCL example as below.
But the result is strange, the total number of output files is random, about 135. I was confused that how the thread started change the value of variable `$thread`.

```
package require Thread
puts "*** I'm thread [thread::id]"

for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 200} {incr thread} {
    set thread_ida $thread
    tsv::set app global_thread_num $thread_ida

    set id [thread::create -joinable {

        puts [ tsv::get app global_thread_num ]
        set thread_id [ tsv::get app global_thread_num ]
        puts "${thread_id}thread_id"
        set outFile "./test/${thread_id}"
        append outFile ".tmd"
        puts $outFile
        set FileOut [open $outFile w+]
        puts $FileOut "${thread_id}thread_id"
    }] ;# thread::create
    puts "*** Started thread $id"
    lappend threadIds $id
} ;# for
puts "*** Existing threads: [thread::names]"
# Wait until all other threads are finished
foreach id $threadIds {
    thread::join $id
}
puts "*** That's all, folks!"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you've got is that these two lines:

```
puts [ tsv::get app global_thread_num ]
set thread_id [ tsv::get app global_thread_num ]
```

are not guaranteed to get the same value at all, nor are they *at all* likely to synchronise with the setting of the shared variable in the outer loop. Threads in Tcl have a reasonable amount of overhead during launch.

Instead, what you should do is make threads with the description of work inside a procedure and then send a simple message to them with the ID to start the real processing; that's much easier to make work.

```
package require Thread
puts "*** I'm thread [thread::id]"

for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 200} {incr thread} {
    set id [thread::create -joinable {
        proc DoWork {thread_id} {
            # Only one puts here
            puts "${thread_id}thread_id"
            set outFile "./test/${thread_id}"
            append outFile ".tmd"
            puts $outFile
            set FileOut [open $outFile w+]
            puts $FileOut "${thread_id}thread_id"
            # Close the channel, please...
            close $FileOut
            # Thread done, and since we're using joinable threads it should die now
            thread::release
        }
        thread::wait
    }] ;# thread::create
    puts "*** Started thread $id"
    lappend threadIds $id
    # Start the work going, passing over the numeric ID in the "message"
    thread::send -async $id [list DoWork $thread]
} ;# for
puts "*** Existing threads: [thread::names]"
# Wait until all other threads are finished
foreach id $threadIds {
    thread::join $id
}
puts "*** That's all, folks!"
```

The key things here are that we create a procedure in each thread (`DoWork`) to receive the message, get the thread to wait for messages with `thread::wait`, and then launch the work by sending a message in with `thread::send -async`. The work destroys the thread with `thread::release`; it needs to do so explicitly otherwise it'll end up back in `thread::wait` waiting for the next message.

---

I'd probably use a thread pool in production code, as they're easier to scale to the hardware available in a particular deployment. The `DoWork` procedure — without the `thread::release` — would be defined in the pool's `-initcmd` option. The `thread::send -async` would be replaced by posting work to the pool, and you'd be waiting for the jobs instead of the threads.

```
package require Thread
puts "*** I'm thread [thread::id]"

set pool [tpool::create -maxworkers 48 -initcmd {
    proc DoWork {thread_id} {
        # Only one puts here
        puts "${thread_id}thread_id"
        set outFile "./test/${thread_id}"
        append outFile ".tmd"
        puts $outFile
        set FileOut [open $outFile w+]
        puts $FileOut "${thread_id}thread_id"
        # Close the channel, please...
        close $FileOut
    }    
}]

for {set thread 1} {$thread <= 200} {incr thread} {
    lappend work [tpool::post -nowait $pool [list DoWork $thread]]
}
# Wait until all work is finished
foreach id $work {
    tpool::wait $pool $id
}
puts "*** That's all, folks!"
tpool::release $pool
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the workload you're _really_ using is more complex; merely writing a single line to each of 200 files is more easily done in a single thread.

Comment: I modify my tcl file  as yours ,it works .thank you very much~ And I finally found my mistake~ haha .I use threads to do  some heavy work ,not just writing a single line to each of 200 files.